# Reducer in react/redux app only working for one action.type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, reducers

In my store.js i have the following code:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action.type)
  if (action.type === 'LOAD_USERS') {
    return {
      ...state,
      users: action.users['users']
    }
  } else if (action.type === 'LOAD_CHATROOMS') {
    return {
      ...state,
      chatRooms: action.chatRooms['chatRooms']
    }
  }
  return state;
}

export default createStore(reducer, {users:[], chatRooms:[]}, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

the code inside the `action.type === 'LOAD_CHATROOMS'` is never accessed for some reason, this is the action file where i set the action type for the reducer:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

const loadUsers = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/session/new.json')
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOAD_USERS', 
        users: response.data
      });
    });
  };
};

const logIn = user => {
  return axios.post('http://localhost:3000/session', {
    user_id: user.id
  })
  .then(response => {
    //TODO do something more relevant
    console.log('loged in');
  });

};

const loadChatRooms = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/session/new.json')
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOAD_CHATROOMS', 
        chatRooms: response.data
      });
    });
  };
};

const enterChatRoom = chatrom => {

};

export { loadUsers, logIn, enterChatRoom, loadChatRooms};
```

The 'Load methods' get the data that i use to populate both components (one for users list and the other one for chatrooms list ), both components are called at the same level in the app.js file.

Basically the output that i'm getting is the first component (users) as expected with the correct list, and the chatrooms component is also rendered but the data is not loaded (since it's corresponding reducer block is not accessed).

Thanks a lot for reading :)

Comment: did `console.log(action.type)` printing  `LOAD_CHATROOMS`?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN no, it only prints LOAD_USERS

Comment: How did u know `loadChatRooms` is calling?Please share related script which calling it

Comment: Add a log statement to `loadChatRooms` and check whether it is called first

Comment: @RavindraRanwala it gets printed before the console.log(action.type)